# IndexError: list assignment index out of range in python

Tags: python, dictionary

IndexError: list assignment index out of range in python
What am i doing wrong. I am an newbie

```
actual_ans_dict = []
for data in prsnobj.result:
    actual_ans_dict[data[0]] = data[1]
    print actual_ans_dict
```

Comment: What is the point of calling a list a dict?

Comment: [] for lists, {} for dictionaries

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`actual_ans_dict` is an empty list. You are trying to set a value to `actual_ans_dict[data[0]]` but an element with this index doesn't exist.
You can change the type of `actual_ans_dict` to [dict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict):

```
actual_ans_dict = {}
for data in prsnobj.result:
    actual_ans_dict[data[0]] = data[1]
    print actual_ans_dict
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because your `actual_ans_dict` is empty, which means, it has not any indexes yet.

```
actual_ans_dict = [None]*max([data[0] for data in prsnobj.result])  # not very pythonic, actualy
for data in prsnobj.result:
    actual_ans_dict[data[0]] = data[1]
    print actual_ans_dict
```

This will give you the ability to assign a value to a particular index.
There is a slightly more correct and shorter way to do it:

```
actual_ans_dict = [data[1] for data in prsnobj.result]
```